# swift array to C array

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know how to map and pass a swift array to a C array ?
and more specifically :

```
var array = Array < Array < Int >> ()
```

to

```
int array[][]
```

?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to do that, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: well somehow you are right, an exact idea sometime can take you far from some sort of understanding. I need to pass a 2d array that I create in swift to a C function to pass it then to a lua function. My C functions are in an objective-C file, I can use NSArray instead of C array but I don't know how to declare a 2d array in Objective-C. So my final idea would be to pass a swift 2d array to lua.

Comment: What a good question! I tried for a while to get it to work, but I just couldn't, haha! The answer is obviously tied to UnsafeMutablePointer or UnsafeMutableBufferPointer, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I'm way out of my comfort zone here, but here goes for a possible answer!

See [this question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/4362740/creating-a-two-dimensional-array-in-objective-c) on how to declare two dimensional arrays in objective-c, it goes something along the way of:

```
int myArray[3][3];
```

And [look here](//developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) for some documentation on bridging or interacting with C api's. Maybe something similar to the following could be of help:

```
var myArray = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

func takesAMutableVoidPointer(x: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)  { /* ... */ }

takesAMutableVoidPointer(&myArray)
```